# Which is the fastest way of accessing JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I want to know what is the best way of accessing a JavaScript object, dot operator or `[]`:

`data.property` or `data["property"]`?

Comment: If the property you want to access is known, use `data.prop`. Otherwise use `data[prop]`. Note that these are different. `data["prop"]`, however, is the same as `data.prop`. Note the quotes. I say this only because I think it is more idiomatic to use the `.` operator.

Comment: Of course, you may *know* the property you want to access, but still have to use associative-array notation. For example, if `prop` contains a character not allowed in dot notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are the same speed. Also, if you are concerned with the level of speed in accessing a field attached to a reference, I think you might be going down the wrong path to tuning your code.

Answer (score 4):

Both are more or less the same, **except** in Safari in which case dot notation is significantly faster.

You're much better off concentrating on DOM manipulation, DOM size, and CSS complexity as major sources of performance problems in Javascript applications.

That said, if you are doing a lot of property access in a loop, a local variable will be much faster than either property access or array lookup. Copy an object property into a variable if it is going to be accessed repeatedly. **Do not use the "with" statement, incidentally.** It can slow down local variable access by introducing another object into the scope chain.

Variables defined in local scope will be accessed far more quickly than those in global, as the Javascript engine first looks through all of the variables locally, then checks all of the variables in global scope. Scopes can nest as well, so the farther up the nesting chain the variable resides the longer it will take to find. That's why it's best to cache something like "document" in a local variable if it is going to be accessed more than once.

Answer (score 0):

I would venture to guess that `data.property` is ever-so-slightly faster, but it may be difficult to measure. Indeed, [JSPerf shows no distinction](http://jsperf.com/javascript-lookup-methods)

Answer (score 0):

The best way of accessing object properties has generally nothing to do with speed. Dot operator is used for syntactic sugar (I.E. `this.hasElements()` is easier to read, write and process in your brain than `this["hasElements"]()`) whenever possible and the brackets are used when the key name is a variable or has illegal characters.